# Combining Standard Deviation (combined measurement uncertainty)

Tags: standard-deviation

Im trying to figure out the combined SD of two set of data. I am working with Mass data and % iron. Each set has its on SD and i want to determine the Mass of the iron +- ?.

Example:

Mass = 50 ± X

Iron % = 10 ± Y

So how do I determine the SD of the Total mass of Iron           Total Iron = 5 ± ?

Comment: how are X and Y related? what's "Total mass of Iron Total Iron"...  do you mean that you're taking the product? What does "SD" in this case *actually mean*, operationally? (If you hadn't told me the value, could I compute it in some way?)